# How to get the change value operation on to my variables like my php editor on Xcode

Tags: php, xcode

I want to get this functionality on to my Xcode. Coming from php editor I can easily change the variables on the fly on to my variables. I am pasting this image, please let me know the equivalent in Xcode.[image]